# N-Channel MOSFET Circuit

Tags: stm32, embedded, hardware

a friend of mine developed this Schematic and Circuit.

The Problem is, on LIN_BUS (please ignore the Name) should be KL15 Volage (13.8V) if the FET switches.

[image]

But if FET1_CNTRL is LOW (0.0V) the Output Voltage @ LIN_BUS is 800mV

If FET1_CNTRL is HIGH (3.3V) the Output Voltage @ LIN_BUS is 800mV

Here is my MCU Config:

[image]

Here is my Code and the Voltage on the BSS123.

```
 HAL_GPIO_WritePin(FET1_CNTL_GPIO_Port, FET1_CNTL_Pin, RESET); // = 13.6V 0V @ D-BSS123
    //HAL_GPIO_WritePin(FET1_CNTL_GPIO_Port, FET1_CNTL_Pin, SET); // = 13.6V 3.3V @ D-BSS123
```

Very strange. Does anybody have a suggest what is faulty here?

If 3.3V on BSS123 the Gate on IRF9362PBF is 0.0V
If 0.0V on BSS123 the Gate on IRF9362PBF is 13.2V

***Edit:***

Added some Load. Got a meassurment fail yesterday. So Drain on IRF9362PbF is allways 800mV. Anyway in which state BSS123 is.

I added 5V / 12V / GND directly to the Gate from IRF9362PbF, but still no changes on Drain side. Tested with different hardware but same result.

I reversed the Tips from the Measurement Tool and connected the GND Cable to the Drain. and the Plus Cable to Vss.

Now I measure +13.8V But in both BSS123 States.

Checked with different Hardware. But same result.

Comment: Have you measured the gate voltage on the P-FETs in both states?

Comment: Are you sure all the connections are correct?

Comment: Have you confirmed that the pinout of the BSS123 matches the library part - not all FETs have the same pinout.

Comment: Yes: 

If 3.3V on BSS123 the Gate on IRF9362PBF is 0.0V
If 0.0V on BSS123 the Gate on IRF9362PBF is 13.2V

Comment: Is there any sort of load on LIN_BUS?

Comment: No, no other stuff.

Comment: You shouldn't expect it to do much of anything without *some* sort of load.  Toss a resistor to ground on there to draw some current for test purposes.

Comment: Added some Load. Got a meassurment fail yesterday. So Drain on IRF9362PbF is allways 800mV. Anyway in which state BSS123 is. 

I added 5V / 12V / GND directly to the Gate from IRF9362PbF, but still no changes on Drain side. Tested with different hardware but same result.

I reversed the Tips from the Measurement Tool and connected the GND Cable to the Drain. and the Plus Cable to Vss. 

Now I measure +13.8V But in both BSS123 States. 

Checked with different Hardware. But same result.

Comment: Strange thing is if I connect both cables to my Hand (so a big resistor) the Mosfet Swich but on the Drain its Negative. I can measure +13.8V from Drain to Vss. 

If I supply my solonoid with the Drain and Vss, the Voltage is allways at 13.8V (no switch) and also the solonoid is not controlled. I dont know but very stranges things happens here.

Comment: Do you have an oscilloscope, or just a multimeter? Hint: if the circuit oscillates for some reason, a multimeter isn't much use. How is the thing constructed mechanically: freeform wired? breadboarded? padboarded? on a PCB? I cannot see any power blocking capacitors in the schematic. What sort of a power supply is used? A 12V battery? If the thing does not oscillate, you need to walk the signal chain from start to end with your multimeter and spot which part does not behave as expected.